# Full images in media.phtml

Tags: media

I've this code on template/default/catalog/product/view/media.phtml page. I want to retrieve full size gallery images to display here in li's under ul's. The problem is that with this code, i'm getting thumbnail size media images.

```
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $imgSize = 286;
?>
<ul class="rr images">
<?php $j=1; ?>
<?php foreach ($_images as $_image): ?> 
    <li class="<?php if ($j==1) echo "current"; echo ""; ?> gal-<?php echo $j?>">
      <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($imgSize, NULL); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>"/>
    </li>
    <?php $j++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

This is what i'm getting now:

[image: This is what i'm getting now]

This is what i want to get:

[image: This is what i want to get]

Please note that the problem is not with the size of the image (thumbnail image is of good size), but the dimensions of it(thumbnail image is cropped).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $_product = $this->getProduct();
  $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
  $imgSize = 286;
?>
<ul class="rr images">
 <?php $j=1; ?>
  <?php foreach ($_images as $_image): ?> 
   <li class="<?php if ($j==1) echo "current"; echo ""; ?> gal-<?php echo $j?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'small_image', $_image->getFile())->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($imgSize, NULL); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>"/>
</li>
<?php $j++; ?>
```

you can gve three options for the **image, small_image,thumbnail** based on you want.

Comment: 'image, small_image,thumbnail' none of these are giving me full size image, as shown in second image of question.
`$_img = '<img id="image" class="img-responsive" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($imgSize, null).'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
        echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');`
this gives full size image, but I'm unable to loop through all images to show them under li's

Comment: hey just you have to change the echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'small_image') try this

Comment: Nops... still not working. I guess the reason is that we can't iterate multiple image this way, considering the foreach loop we are using `<?php foreach ($_images as $_image): ?> `

Comment: may be but refer the template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml file you got the proper idea how magento display image on detail page.